# Guice @Inject not able to inject with multiple constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I will start with the over view of the problem that I am facing with an example.

```
class abstract A {
   @Inject
   A() {}

   @Inject
   A(A1 a1, A2 a2) {
      this.a1 =a1;
      this.a2 =a2;
   }
   public abstract doSomething();
   A1 a1;
   A2 a2;
}

class B extends A {

   @Inject
   A(A3 a3) {
      this.a3 =a3;
   }
   public doSomething() {
          System.out.println("some work");
   };
   A3 a3;
}
class C extends A {

   @Inject
   A(A4 a4) {
      this.a4 =a4;
   }
   public doSomething() {
          System.out.println("some work");
   };
   A4 a4;
}
```

Class B and C extends A using default constructor of A. So in class A, argument constructor is not invoked and the fields I want to be injected is null.
I don't want to use field level @Inject. I want to use constructor injection. If that is not possible please provide with alternative solution.

Comment: What code do you use to get a instance?

Comment: As you said: when calling C's constructor, the no-arg constructor of A is called. So how could A1 and A2 possibly be injected. The rules of Java are the rules of Java. If you want A1 and A2 to be injected when constructing a C, then add them as arguments to the C constructor, and call super(a1, a2) as the first instruction.

Comment: I will use a function which will return B or C object with which I will invoke the abstract function. I am just giving the template view of my problem here.
The class having the function which will return the object B or C also use constructor injection for B and C.

Comment: @JBNizet is this is the only way to solve here?

Comment: With constructor injection, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things here:

- You can have at most one `@Inject`-annotated constructor per class.
- Annotating with `@Inject` on abstract class doesn't make sense (it won't be instantiated anyway).
- Your `B` and `C` are invoking no-args constructors because not specifying one is equivalent to calling `super()`. When you fix that (i.e. explicitly call `super(a1, a2)` with **two** arguments), you'd be good (and it doesn't have to do anything with dependency injection).